# Error Migrating Comment Framework Into Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use Django's built-in Comment framework for a project I am working on.  According to the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/comments/) the first 2 steps are:

1. Install the comments framework by adding `'django.contrib.comments'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`
2. Run `python manage.py migrate` so that Django will create the comments tables.

So I did exactly that and got the following error

> comments.Comment.site: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Site', which is either not installed, or is abstract.

I don't really know went wrong because all I did was add that one line to the `INSTALLED_APPS` and then ran `migrate`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you added `django.contrib.sites` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` and set `SITE_ID=1` in your `settings.py`?

Comment: I haven't added those yet.  Where does it specify that I need to do that?

Comment: from your error, it shows a missing model `Site` which shows you haven't put this into your INSTALLED_APPS, give it a go and see if that helps.

Comment: it's shown from the migration file `0001_initial.py`: `dependencies = [
        ('sites', '0001_initial'),
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('contenttypes', '0001_initial'),
    ]`.

Comment: It worked.  I wonder why the documentation doesn't tell me I need to add the Sites stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `django.contrib.sites` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` and set `SITE_ID=1` in your `settings.py`.

It's shown from the error:

> Field defines a relation with model 'Site', which is either not installed, or is abstract.

And from the migration file [source code](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments/blob/master/django_comments/migrations/0001_initial.py):

```
dependencies = [ ('sites', '0001_initial'), migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL), ('contenttypes', '0001_initial'), ]
```

It suggested that `django.contrib.sites` is indeed a dependency app.

#### Edited:

In fact, this is included from the docs [**Quick start guide**](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments/blob/master/docs/quickstart.txt):

> Enable the "sites" framework  by adding    'django.contrib.sites' to `INSTALLED_APPS`
>   and defining    `SITE_ID`.